# nginx: Docker container fails to start

Tags: docker, nginx, webpack, docker-compose, webpack-dev-server

In an attempt to Dockerize an application in four containers, the Nginx container is failing with an error. Specifically when I’ve run `docker-compose up` it displays:

```
nginx_1   | 2019/12/25 23:00:50 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "client:8080" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2
nginx_1   | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "client:8080" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2
```

The `docker-compose.yml` and the nginx configuration and [ETA] the nginx container's `Dockerfile.dev` are included below. Things I’ve tried:

- In `docker-compose.yml`, setting the nginx container to

```
depends_on: 
  - client
```

- In `default.conf`, adding `resolver 127.0.0.11;` in the `location /` section of the server block

I’m somewhat unfamiliar with nginx and Docker. So I’d appreciate any help or insights.

---

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
  nginx:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ../nginx-glen
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3050:80'
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ../cornish-glen
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ../cornish-glen:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - PGUSER=postgres
      - PGHOST=postgres
      - PGDATABASE=turnip_glen
      - PGPASSWORD=********
      - PGPORT=5432
  client:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: .
    depends_on:
      - api
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
    environment:
      - GRAPHQL_ORIGIN=http://api:3099
```

---

`default.conf`

```
upstream client {
  server client:8080;
}

upstream api {
  server api:3099;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://client;
  }

  location /sockjs-node {
    proxy_pass http://client;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }

  location /graphql {
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }
}
```

---

**ETA** `nginx-glen/Dockerfile.dev`

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: What's in `../nginx-glen/Dockerfile.dev`?

Comment: Can you try adding port mapping for client and api services. Also check if you are able to wget client:8080 from nginx container to debug further.

Comment: @DavidMaze Added to the bottom.

Comment: @asolanki 
I added port mapping as you suggested (e.g. `ports:\n  - '8080:8080'`). Got the same error in the nginx container. Then I tried the `wget` to no avail; see output reproduced here.

  `$ docker exec -it turnip-glen_nginx_1 bash`

  `root@7a758732fce0:/# wget client:8080`

  `--2019-12-27 19:44:56--  http://client:8080/`

  `Resolving client (client)... 172.22.0.4`

  `Connecting to client (client)|172.22.0.4|:8080... failed: Connection refused.`

Comment: This may be a webpack problem. The webpack dev server is serving on `localhost:8080`. It needs to be serving on the IP address that nginx sets up for `client`, I think. So I may have to rewrite this question.

Comment: I hacked this together by adding `disableHostCheck: true` to the `devServer` object in the webpack dev config. It's insecure but will do for development purposes. I'll add the webpack tag & post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in the webpack development server, which needs to be instructed to be flexible about the host in the following way:

```js
// Only showing the devServer object here:
  devServer: {
    // These two lines are the relevant ones:
    // ---
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    disableHostCheck: true, // TODO: insecure, but probably fine for dev environment
    // ---
    contentBase: "./public",
    index: ''
  }
```

I'll also point out that the nginx container's `[emerg]` messages in the Docker logs do not seem to prevent the application from running.